# which tomcat service gets started while running a jar from terminal

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat

As i had created a jar from my project, i had started running it from linux terminal using the command

```
java -jar snapShot.jar
```

By running this my project works fine and gives console output as

```
 INFO 2018-06-26 13:34:25 [main] -Registering beans for JMX exposure 
 on startup
 INFO 2018-06-26 13:34:25 [main] -Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 
 (http)
 INFO 2018-06-26 13:34:25 [main] -Started DomainApplication in 12.143 
 seconds (JVM running for 12.662)
```

I have another Tomcat in my local system. Apache Tomcat Version 8.5.29 .
But while running the jar file in terminal i found another tomcat service is running. Actually which gets started?

Comment: Have you stopped the tomcat which started through this jar? Try calling shutdown.bat for both the tomcat and try again

Comment: Clarify " i found another tomcat service is running."

Comment: Its probably because there is an embedded tomact in the jar. Whenever the jar is executed this tomcat runs.

Comment: yes great ,i found the thing that its having an embedded tomcat in jar. What about the ports it chooses to run.